# Determine network SSID from JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have a web page with multiple different links (simple  html tags), some of which are valid if connected to network 'X' and some are valid if connected to network 'Y'.  Is it possible to find the name of the network that the user is currently connected to in order to display only the valid links?

Comment: You most accurate guess would be to inspect the user's ip address. SSID is a purely wireless thing, wired networks don't even have an ssid.

Comment: For this kind of work, you'll need to configure your various routers correctly, you can't really do this from Java, and certainly not from JSP.